# Possible bot idea: Should 1-off bad reviews in First Post/Late Post queue be reported?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, moderation, first-post-review

This is a bit of a cross post from my question on [meta.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317341/should-1-off-bad-reports-in-first-post-late-post-queue-be-reported), because this mainly has to do with review queues, and my idea would mainly target Stack Overflow.

> Say we have [this
>   review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/21251299):
>
> [image]
>
> This is an obviously bad review here, as the post should have at least
>   been met with a flag/comment, as this is clearly NAA.
>
> My question boils down to the following:
>
> - Should this be something that should be flagged?
> - To ♦ moderators: If I do report this, what are the repercussions from this? Would this be [review-ban](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/review-ban) worthy, on the first
>     mistake? Is this something that would you want to see and track from
>     the first mistake, or something that should be reported/tracked after
>     *n* or more mistakes? If so, what is *n*?

I'm seeking input from ♦ moderators, because I want to find out what your feeling is if these are automatically reported. [Natty](https://stackapps.com/questions/7049) currently runs in the [SOBotics](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics) channel on SO. It examines NATO posts, and experienced users rate questions as TP: They're NAA, or FP: It looks fine. I wanted to piggy back on that data, pull all verified posts that were confirmed NAA, examine the related First Post/NATO review for that post, and then auto flag to a moderator if the review completed as 'No Action Needed'. What are your thoughts?

For the last 3 days, I've attached some sample data of posts that would have been caught, with this algorithm, which accounts for ~ 8 posts a day. I feel like even if the review below doesn't have any actionable action, it still may indicate a possible bad deletion (On the VLQ queue).

[53051731](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53051731)   [Sentinel](https://sentinel.erwaysoftware.com/posts/aid/53051731)   4            [late answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/21269569)
  [53049813](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53049813)   [Sentinel](https://sentinel.erwaysoftware.com/posts/aid/53049813)   7            [late answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/21268587)
  [53045412](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53045412)   [Sentinel](https://sentinel.erwaysoftware.com/posts/aid/53045412)   4.5          [late answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/21266219)
  [53038119](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53038119)   [Sentinel](https://sentinel.erwaysoftware.com/posts/aid/53038119)   4            [late answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/21261720)
  [53035294](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53035294)   [Sentinel](https://sentinel.erwaysoftware.com/posts/aid/53035294)   4.5          [late answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/21260040)
  [53035252](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53035252)   [Sentinel](https://sentinel.erwaysoftware.com/posts/aid/53035252)   6            [late answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/21260039)
  [53033653](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53033653)   [Sentinel](https://sentinel.erwaysoftware.com/posts/aid/53033653)   4.5          [late answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/21259197)
  [53032243](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53032243)   [Sentinel](https://sentinel.erwaysoftware.com/posts/aid/53032243)   5            [first post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/21258341)
  [53029865](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53029865)   [Sentinel](https://sentinel.erwaysoftware.com/posts/aid/53029865)   4            [late answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/21257091)
  [53028947](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53028947)   [Sentinel](https://sentinel.erwaysoftware.com/posts/aid/53028947)   5.5          [first post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/21257572)
  [53028086](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53028086)   [Sentinel](https://sentinel.erwaysoftware.com/posts/aid/53028086)   4.5          [first post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/21255875)
  [53027686](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53027686)   [Sentinel](https://sentinel.erwaysoftware.com/posts/aid/53027686)   4.5          [first post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/21255602)
  [53027568](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53027568)   [Sentinel](https://sentinel.erwaysoftware.com/posts/aid/53027568)   4.5          [first post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/21255532)
  [53027568](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53027568)   [Sentinel](https://sentinel.erwaysoftware.com/posts/aid/53027568)   4.5          [late answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/21255578)
  [53026740](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53026740)   [Sentinel](https://sentinel.erwaysoftware.com/posts/aid/53026740)   4.5          [late answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/21255071)
  [53024017](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53024017)   [Sentinel](https://sentinel.erwaysoftware.com/posts/aid/53024017)   4.5          [first post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/21253374)
  [53023354](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53023354)   [Sentinel](https://sentinel.erwaysoftware.com/posts/aid/53023354)   5.5          [first post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/21252965)
  [53022883](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53022883)   [Sentinel](https://sentinel.erwaysoftware.com/posts/aid/53022883)   6            [late answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/21252803)
  [53021942](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53021942)   [Sentinel](https://sentinel.erwaysoftware.com/posts/aid/53021942)   3.5/manual   [late answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/21252193)
  [53021443](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53021443)   [Sentinel](https://sentinel.erwaysoftware.com/posts/aid/53021443)   7.5          [first post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/21251843)
  [53020797](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53020797)   [Sentinel](https://sentinel.erwaysoftware.com/posts/aid/53020797)   5.5          [first post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/21251391)
  [53020672](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53020672)   [Sentinel](https://sentinel.erwaysoftware.com/posts/aid/53020672)   4            [late answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/21251402)
  [53020551](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53020551)   [Sentinel](https://sentinel.erwaysoftware.com/posts/aid/53020551)   6.5          [late answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/21251299)
  [53019167](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53019167)   [Sentinel](https://sentinel.erwaysoftware.com/posts/aid/53019167)   5            [late answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/21250394)
  [53018467](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53018467)   [Sentinel](https://sentinel.erwaysoftware.com/posts/aid/53018467)   4.5          [late answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/21249910)
  [52733210](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52733210)   [Sentinel](https://sentinel.erwaysoftware.com/posts/aid/52733210)   1/manual     [late answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/21088267)

Gist [here](https://gist.github.com/danbopes/77f2611b40da6b4f360e1636333b1968) for a slightly better formatted table.

Comment: How ironic.. looks like you *edited* that not-an-answer, which probably shouldn't require editing as it's... not an answer.

Comment: @jpp I edit them to avoid being edited out of the VLQ queue (Because they have obvious formatting issues, and some people correct the formatting issues, leaving it still NAA). As the answer is still NAA, it requires a reflag for moderator intervention, so this step avoids a bit of the mess.

Comment: I left [my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317432/135615) on the Meta.SE version of this, because this does seem to apply across the network. In short, two obviously terrible recent reviews (within the last few days) is definitely worth flagging, and one obviously terrible recent might also be worth reporting. On SO, we regularly get manual flags from people about this, so it is a common case we deal with. Might want to try out with a sample query first to see how noisy this is, though.

Comment: I believe the bot would have to have 10k to be able to see the [global review history](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/history) page. Prior to 10k it just shows your own history IIRC. This means running the bot under your own account and accepting the consequences against your account if the bot goes haywire and starts wreaking havoc.